# display text on screen - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, text

Hi
I am planning a simple experiment in MATLAB. I need to print a colored text on the screen, inverted. I found the function

```
text(0.6,0.5,'red','rotation',180,'fontsize',50,'color','k')
```

But I want to get rid of the axis (x and y), I want just the text to be presented in the center of the screen..
any ideas would be appriciated.
ariel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
figure
set(gcf,'Color', 'white')
text(0.6,0.5,'red','rotation',180,'fontsize',50,'color','r')
set(gca,'Color','white');
set(gca,'XColor','white');
set(gca,'YColor','white');
```

Comment: thanks, it helps but I still have a grey background? how can I fill it with white?

Comment: @user552231: added a *set(gca,'Color','white');*. This should override possible platform dependent settings.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively:

```
figure('Color','white', 'Menu','none')
text(0.5, 0.5, 'red', 'Rotation',180, 'FontSize',50, 'Color','k', ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','Center', 'VerticalAlignment','Middle')
axis off
```

[image]